# JSF 2.0 Passing object between request scope beans using a link

Tags: java, jsf

for some time I'm trying to pass an object between two pages, that are using different managed beans. I'm using jsf 2.1 and primefaces 3.1.

My case:

1. I have a **p:dataTable** and one column is a *h:link* where the user can click to edit the current object
2. after clicking a new page will be open, where the content of the selected object will be displayed for further actions

I've tried sending some parameters from page 1 as GET request and process them from page 2. It works, but this is not the solution I want. I need the whole object that was selected. I was thinking to pass it in the request map, or to declare the bean responsible for page 1 as @SessionScoped and to inject this bean from the second one.

What I don't succeed is to find out which object was selected before changing the page. I've tried using ajax, or an actionListener for the link tags, but nothing works. Before performing the actionListener or the ajax event, the page is changed...

How can I first set the selected object/row and only after that change the page?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `h:link`, you would want to use `p:commandLink`, set the selected object in `actionListener`, and change the page in `oncomplete` phase, with a javascript line like `location = 'page2.xhtml';`.

You can find the related tag documentation below. It also exists in version 3.1.

http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/commandLink.html

PS: Either page 1 or page 2 still needs to be session-scoped, otherwise it won't work.